# How can I do redirects in turns

Tags: .htaccess

If `TURNO_ACTUAL` is undefined or greater than 3, set `CURRENT_SHIFT` to 1

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:TURNO_ACTUAL} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{ENV:TURNO_ACTUAL} >3
RewriteRule ^ - [E=TURNO_ACTUAL:1]
```

And for this valor can redirect to 3 options, the problem is that i cant make that `TURNO_ACTUAL` increments 1 for every redirect o enter in the url that redirects

Comment: Environment variables contain _strings_ . I doubt you can use them as numbers as you are trying to ...

Comment: You have any idea how to do this?

Comment: You need to explain more precisely what you are trying to do and _how_ you are trying to do it. (How is `TURNO_ACTUAL` being set initially?) "set `CURRENT_SHIFT` to 1" - The rule you've posted is "OK", except you are setting `TURNO_ACTUAL` to "1", not `CURRENT_SHIFT`? "can redirect to 3 options" - What 3 options? What redirects? How? "i cant make that TURNO_ACTUAL increments 1 for every redirect" - And where/how are you trying to do this? You cannot _mathematically_ "increment" a number in `.htaccess`, but you can hard-code this if the values are limited (you say there are only 3 options).

Comment: "or greater than 3" - How much "greater" can it be? 4-9 (single digit) is OK, but if 10+ (and no "0" prefixing) then you will need to use the `-gt` integer operator.

Comment: @arkascha "Environment variables contain strings" - Yes, but mod_rewrite provides various operators that allow you to compare it lexicographically (`>`) or (effectively typecasting) as an integer (`-gt`).